# How to get the value from txt file for a particular string in bash

Tags: bash

My requirement is Firstly, I want to search the string(ABC/AME/EDF, etc) in file.txt after that want to get the value for that string(like for example string='EDF' and I want to get the value for EDF[var2] which is 0)

file.txt

```
ABC:
  var1: 0
  var2: 0
EDF:
  var1: 0
 var2: 1
AME:
  var1: 0
  var2: dfl
FOk:
  var1: 0
  var2: 1
UMP:
  var1: 0
  var2: +def=
```

bdf.sh

```
 source file.txt

if [[$EDF[var2] -eq 1]]
then 
        echo "--------------------------------------";
else
    
    echo "=========================================";
fi
```

Comment: Is the input actually YAML format? Or can the indentation be inconsistent (your EDF/var2 is not indented the same as the rest?

Comment: with well-formed YAML, extracting value is just `yq <file.txt .EDF.var2`

Comment: From the sample input, I would expect EDF[VAR2] to be 1

Comment: @user21917643 : my requirement, Firstly, is do you own homework

Comment: @jhnc : Yes the input file is yaml file

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

source <(
    awk -F: '
        /^.*:$/{
            str=$1; print "declare -A " str"=()"; next
        }
        {
            for(i=1;i<=2;i++) gsub(/^ +/,"",$i); 
            print str"["$1"]=\""$2"\""
        }
    ' file.txt
)


echo ${EDF[var2]}
echo ${AME[var2]}
```

---

```
1
dfl
```